# Firebase to connect with another database

Tags: firebase

I am new to firebase and i wonder if there is any way to connect firebase with one joomla database that i have already in one server.

Is there any way to connect my iOS app with firebase and firebase to take the data from my external database from another server?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/kjit2v1Ua4E

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect Firebase to another database, but you can use the mobile device as a bridge between Firebase and another database.
**OUTPUT** :
In my case I took data from a web service and put it into the Firebase, after that I read that data from firestore. 
**INPUT**:
I wrote data from a mobile device, sent it  to Firebase and after that I "synchronizes" (sending data) everything with the web service.